# How to safely transmit authentication to a REST API?

Tags: rest, http

Our web server implements a stateless JSON API (no login step). Until now, all of our endpoints have been `POST`-only, with the authentication information included in the `POST` body:

```
POST /api/getData
{
  "apiKey": "I5r8ccXa8BLgoO50iZpunOGyf0h5e28L1exNpV5m5LI"
  "userId": "8A7tRggxWjyQ+grQIwkAswtaityHhtQm0NTFGD5wnmM="
  "passwordAuth": "p0/yv/Ptv8kOAY1k2NpR9EhwvGA/n/DF79JGaKJmF/k="
  "otpToken": "913012"
}
```

This isn't very REST-ful, obviously. We would like to use HTTP `GET` requests for our read-only requests, but that means sending the authentication information in a different way. There are many possibilities:

- Put it in the URI?
- Put it in a cookie?
- Put it in a custom HTTP `Authentication` header?
- Invent our own custom HTTP headers?

Which one is better, and why? Or, is a `POST` body still the safest way to transmit arbitrary authentication information?

The client is a typical phone app, but we may do a browser version one day. Everything runs over HTTPS. The password hashing and other crypto stuff runs on the client (our app does end-to-end encryption).

Answer (score 0):

All five options basically work, but they each present their own tradeoffs:

- URI's often end up in logs. If the URI contains any sensitive information, you will either have to sanitize your server logs or treat them with the same level of security as your password database. Both options suck.
- Browsers automatically send cookies with each request. If an attacker can trick the user into visiting a URI like `your-app.com/resetpassword` (by putting it in an `<img>` tag, for example), the request will be fully authenticated. The attacker doesn't even need to know what the credentials *are* for this to work. This is called a CSRF bug.
- Custom `Authentication` protocols are indeed allowed by the HTTP spec, but many frameworks are geared towards the standard mechanisms. If you go this route, you may end up fighting your own tools to make things work.
- Custom headers are generally usable. Many CSRF protection techniques rely on a custom header like `X-Csrf-Token` for their implementation, and there aren't any broad compatibility problems.

Given all this, custom HTTP headers may be the way to go for your application.